Can I screw into a cladded beam to add a ceiling fan?

I want to add a large ceiling fan, obviously I need to add a junction box of some nature. I was wondering if there is a recommended method to mount to the beam.

Is that beam well supported?  It looks like it might be more decoration than structural, mounted better than just a few nails/screws holding it up.

I pulled off the cladding and there was a solid wood beam inside of it. My friend assumes it's an LVL support beam (he didn't look at it in person, just based off this picture). If it's LVL, then I believe I'm not suppose to screw into it.

....where did you get that you're not supposed to drive screws into a LVL from...?

Are you asking if you can mount a JB to the beam and/or cladding, or mount the ceiling fan to it?  Also, how is the cladding fastened to the LVL?

How do you think the LVL is attached to the house if not with screws or nails?

Thanks everyone for the feedback. I read that structural screws or through bolts are recommended for LVL. The cladding is fastened to LVL with nails as far as I can tell, at least the panels I was able to remove from the beam to check was inside. There were online concerns about screwing into the center of LVLs online, but wasn't sure. I briefly spoke to a structural engineer today who stated fabricating a stirrup to connect to the neutral axis of the beam is recommended, though I'm not sure if it is required.
